# MySQL error: “Column count doesn't match value count at row 1” with php

Tags: php

I dont know why the heck I'm getting this error, I tested it using only one column and one value and it stills displays it, here's my code:

```
if($insert_company = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO company(company_name) VALUES(?)")){
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert_company , 's', $company_name);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($insert_company );

  if(mysqli_stmt_error($insert_company )) {
    printf('Error2: %s<br>File: %s<br>Line: %s', mysqli_stmt_error($insert_company ), basename(__FILE__), __LINE__);
    mysqli_stmt_close($insert_company );
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    exit;
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_close($insert_company );
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    echo "<script>alert('Okay');</script>";
  }
} else {
  printf('Error: %s<br>File: %s<br>Line: %s', mysqli_error($mysqli), basename(__FILE__), __LINE__);
  mysqli_close($mysqli);
  exit;
}
```

It only happens in php because when I use it through mysql commands it works....

Comment: Still missing your actual code.

Comment: @AmalMurali What relevant code is missing? If it's going into the `else` clause, the `//code` part is irrelevant.

Comment: VALUES(?) ? it is not getting the value, show us where you bind the parameter...that part is not working

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_pram();

Answer (score 0):

Where are you passing value to 'company_name'. Your code should be like this:

```
$insert_company = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO company(company_name) VALUES(?)");
$insert_company->bind_param("s", "The company name");
$insert_company->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you has the query inside the if(check condition) and it always return false because it doesn't has yet the bind value and the query fails, assign a variable to the query and after, is that you can check for the result:

```
$insert_company = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO company(company_name) VALUES(?)")
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($insert_company , 's', $company_name);
mysqli_stmt_execute($insert_company )
```

Now the if()

```
 if($insert_company){
  //do whatever
 }else{
 //do not whatever
 }
```